# Woocommerce не отображает локализацию в продакшине?

Tags: woocommerce

Поставил WP. Поставил платную тему Avada. В это теме шел Woo. В Woo всё переведено (перевод расположен по пути `/wp-content/languages/plugins/woocommerce-ru_RU.(mo и po))`. По офф. документации Woo всё должно работать. Но в продакшине полностью всё на английском, почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Avada перекрывает шаблоны WooCommerce своими. Они находятся в папке /wp-content/themes/avada/woocommerce

И неизвестно, какой текстовый домен (в функциях [gettext](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)) там используется. Если 'woocommerce', и текст совпадает с текстом WooCommerce, то перевод подхватится. Если другой домен или текст, отсутствующий в WooCommerce, то переводу взяться неоткуда.

Надо смотреть файлы .po в теме и переводить их.